# Is it possible to run Interbase 2007 server with a windows user with restricted access?

Tags: interbase

I'm working on a legacy software and sundenly it became a requirement to run interbase server (Interbase 2007) logged with a restricted user.

We tried this here (not me) but no client is able to connect to the server, including IBConsole, like no Interbase server were instaled. Even whether both running in the same computer.

Is it possible to run Interbase 2007 server with a windows user with restricted access?

Answer (score 0):

The *client* can connect as a restricted user, but the server is a Windows service, and you need to be the Administrator to install that. You should configure InterBase to start automatically.

Comment: No problem if I need to install it as Administrator, but after install, I need to run it as a Restricted User.

Comment: That will work. You may need to use a "remote" (localhost) connection, but it will work.